# Unable to implement custom enum wrapper for std::error::Error

Tags: rust, error-handling

I am trying to figure out how the error enum works to wrap `std::error:Error` by passing in bad input for `Url`. I wish to wrap `url::ParseError`.

```
use std::error::Error;
use std::fmt::Display;

#[derive(Debug)]
pub enum WordCount {
    UrlError(url::ParseError),
}

impl Display for WordCount {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut std::fmt::Formatter<'_>) -> std::fmt::Result {
        match self {
            WordCount::UrlError(e) => {
                write!(f, "{}", e)
            },
        }
    }
}

impl std::error::Error for WordCount {}

impl From<url::ParseError> for WordCount {
    fn from(err: url::ParseError) -> Self {
        WordCount::UrlError(err)
    }
} 

pub fn run() -> Result<String, WordCount> {
    let args: Vec<String> = env::args().collect();
    let arg = &args[1].as_ref();
    let domain = Url::parse(arg);

    match domain {
        Ok(_) => {}
        Err(err) => return Err(WordCount::UrlError(err)),
   };

    Ok("".to_owned())
}
```

If I replace the following line:
`Err(err) => return Err(WordCount::UrlError(err)),` in the `fn run()`

with: `panic!("some string")` e.g

```
   match domain {
    Ok(domain) => println!("happy domain"),
    Err(err) => panic!("panicking"),
};
```

Then I can see an error print to the terminal. But not with the implementation, nothing prints to `stderr` even if I have implemented `Display`.

Comment: Unless with panics, just returning an error does not print anything to the console, the calling function has to get the error itself and print it explicitly. But you do not show the code that calls `run()`. Maybe it is just printing nothing?

Comment: @rodrigo yes your right, thanks! If I put the parsing logic in its own function and call it then use the `match arm` on its return, it prints the custom error. Can I avoid using `match` on the caller code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just returning an error doesn't implicetly print it. You could make your **main** function to return the same error, then your program will report the message at the end of execution. As an example:

```rust
use url::Url;
use std::error::Error;
use std::fmt::Display;

#[derive(Debug)]
pub enum CrawlerError {
    UrlError(url::ParseError),
}

impl Display for CrawlerError {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut std::fmt::Formatter<'_>) -> std::fmt::Result {
        match self {
            CrawlerError::UrlError(e) => {
                write!(f, "{}", e)
            },
        }
    }
}

impl std::error::Error for CrawlerError {}

impl From<url::ParseError> for CrawlerError {
    fn from(err: url::ParseError) -> Self {
        CrawlerError::UrlError(err)
    }
} 

pub fn run() -> Result<String, CrawlerError> {
    let domain = Url::parse("foo/bar");

    match domain {
        Ok(_) => Ok("".to_string()),
        Err(err) => Err(CrawlerError::UrlError(err)),
   }

}

fn main() -> Result<(), CrawlerError> {
    run()?;
    Ok(())
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=f054b55d10591c61cf20855e4c4ba992)

Results:

```
   Compiling playground v0.0.1 (/playground)
    Finished dev [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 1.25s
     Running `target/debug/playground`
Error: UrlError(RelativeUrlWithoutBase)
```